# c++ how do you store a full string into a string array using getline?

Tags: c++

After it gets the first string and first double the program doesn't get the other strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i< NUM_MOVIES; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "How much did " << names[i] << " earn <in millions>: ";
    cin >> earnings[i];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second time you call `getline` you are actually reading a newline character because `cin >>` does not discard newline characters *after* the value it has just read.

So you end up in this cycle of reading bad data. Try this:

```
getline(cin >> std::ws, names[i]);
```

Comment: @user3462406: `std::cin >> std::ws` will eat up all whitespace characters (newlines, tabs, spaces), effectively bringing the stream to the next non-whitespace character for reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> earnings[i];
```

This should correct as follows

```
getline(cin, earnings[i])
```

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string names[10];
  string earnings[10];
  for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "How much did " << names[i] << " earn <in millions>: ";
    getline(cin, earnings[i]);
    cout << endl;
}
cout<< names[0]<< names[1]<<"\n";
cout<<earnings[0] << earnings[1]<<"\n";
return 0;

}
```

Comment: earnings is a double array, sorry. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `>>` doesn't read past the end of line so the following `std::getline()` does that instead of grabbing your next input.

You can use `std::ws` (absorb whitespace chars):

```
for (int i = 0; i< NUM_MOVIES; i++)
{
    cin >> std::ws; // clear previous line

    cout << "Enter the name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "How much did " << names[i] << " earn <in millions>: ";
    cin >> earnings[i];
    cout << endl;
}
```